# Did anyone try to set keyboard fixed on screen with angular 6?

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I am trying to use Mat-keyboard but the focus on input changes when I click the keyboard. Please see the image below -

[displayed view of my keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geJZd.png)

```html
<form ngForm="myForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Code" type="text" name="code">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-keyboard></mat-keyboard>
 </form>
```

I want to achieve something this blog shows on angular 6: 
Kindly visit to get more clarity
https://rawgit.com/GreenfieldVentures/angular-on-screen-keyboard/master/demo2.html

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use `<mat-keyboard>` on it's own - it says so in the [docs](https://ngx-material-keyboard.github.io/core/components/MatKeyboardComponent.html#source):

> A component used to open as the default keyboard, matching material spec. This should only be used internally by the keyboard service.

Only use it as a directive:

```
<input matInput matKeyboard placeholder="Code" type="text" name="code">
```

You can [read more](https://ngx-material-keyboard.github.io/core/index.html) on it on the docs site.

Comment: The problem is that I have to fix the matKeyboard on screen, not when I click on the input

Comment: Then maybe put the matKeyboard directive on the top-level component of the given view, maybe even on, say, app-component. Or alternatively, look at MatKeyboardService.open() method: https://ngx-material-keyboard.github.io/core/injectables/MatKeyboardService.html and events. I see that it also binds  @HostListener events to focus and blur - maybe add your own directive there that stops event propagation and simply open the service once, automatically and never let 'blur' event reach it. Or have a periodic interval which checks if isOpen is true and reopens it if not - which would be ugly.